# Setting variables in TFS RMI tasks

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

TFS release management has a concept of variables. They're set in the release definition at design time. Is there a way for tasks to change variables so that other tasks see the changes?

The Windows `SET` command only affects the environment of the currently executing instance of cmd.exe, it doesn't affect the enclosing process' environment.

Passing info from step to step in a temp file in the working folder is possible, but crude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe so.  I have not tested this, but take a look at this VSO Build Task:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks

It has a task where it can set the variable. Here is the specific powershell script it calls:

https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-variable-tasks/blob/master/vsts-variable-set/vsts-variable-set.ps1

Line 22:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($VariableName);]$Value"
```

UPDATE:
I have since found Microsoft documentation here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md
Specifically:

> ### vso[task.setvariable]value
>
> variable=variable name (Required) 
>   issecret=true (Optional) 
>   Sets a variable in the variable service of taskcontext. The first task can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the variable. The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable. When issecret is set to true, the value of the variable will be saved as secret and masked out from log. Secret variables are not passed into tasks as environment variables and must be passed as inputs.
>   Examples:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue

##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;issecret=true;]testvalue
```